# Problem using noise node, pixelated noise texture in output

Tags: node-editor

I was watching a tutorial on using the noise node and wanted to follow it to create this:
[image: noise node output]

But I followed the tutorial and got this pixelated texture instead:
[image: squarish]
How do I fix this?

Comment: You have made a mistake when following the tutorial. I suggest starting fresh and following it again in a new file. You didn't provide enough info to give any precise answer.

Comment: it was a new file that i tested it in, i followed it step by step, here is the tutorial https://youtu.be/KmvaCxnjj8A

Comment: What version of Blender are you using - certainly pre-2.80. Can you try it on a more up to date version? It looks to be possibly a bug in the version you're using. With the Vector input of the texture node disconnected, Blender should be using *Generated* coordinates which should not be causing any such "stepping" of values.

Comment: I've seen behavior like this when texture coordinate location is VERY far away from the origin.

Comment: I'm using 2.79 in this version, they were also using 2.79 in the tutorial, also it's not very far away from the origin.

Comment: Can you list the exact steps taken to produce this from the default cube on your version so others can replicate it? Also, what addons do you have installed? Presuming the “Viewer” node is Node Wrangler. Are there other nodes that aren’t visible in your screenshot? A second Material Output perhaps?

Comment: nope those are all the nodes there are, i just created a plane, added a material and added the same nodes in the picture.

Comment: Did this ever get solved?  Is it possible your default file has some funky render settings?